# Angular and PWA

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

Do we need to add below events for browser to show add to screen icon or not.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
      /* Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt*/
      e.preventDefault();
      // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
      this.deferredPrompt = e;
      btnAdd.style.display = 'block';
    });

btnAdd.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      // hide our user interface that shows our A2HS button
      btnAdd.style.display = 'none';
      // Show the prompt
      this.deferredPrompt.prompt();
      // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
      this.deferredPrompt.userChoice
        .then((choiceResult) => {
          if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
            console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt');
          } else {
            console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt');
          }
          this.deferredPrompt = null;
        });
    });
```

I am asking this question to clear doubt because from chrome version 68+
Below note from https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/ 
Attention: Beginning in Chrome 68 (beta in early June 2018), Chrome will not automatically show the Add to Home Screen banner, instead, you can show it by calling prompt() on the beforeinstallprompt 
event with a user gesture. See Updates to Add to Home Screen Behavior for full details.

Also, on Mac OS i am not able to delete/unregister the icon added to applications by using the developer tools.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That works as expected in the current version of Chrome (tested on Android)

Chrome Beta (68) is still a work in progress
There is a new/temporary mini-infobar that currently ignores preventDefault()

From this page
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/a2hs-updates
"The mini-infobar will appear when the site meets the add to home screen criteria, regardless of whether you preventDefault() on the beforeinstallprompt event or not."